# Are these definitions of oblivious Turing machines equivalent?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

I'm confused about the definition of an *oblivious Turing machine*. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2655568/477746) answer (and the comments below it), it can be defined as follows.

1. A **type-1 oblivious Turing machine** is a *new* kind of machine (not an ordinary Turing machine), which is similar to an ordinary Turing machine, except:

- The transition function does not specify the head movement;
- In addition to the transition function, the definition of each machine includes a *head movement function* $s(i, |x|)$, which tells the tape head how to move on step $i$, given an input $x$ of length $|x|$.

However, there is another possible definition, which I think is actually a more natural interpretation of the quote from [Arora & Barak](https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf) in the answer cited above:

2. A **type-2 oblivious Turing machine** is an ordinary Turing machine, which happens to satisfy the following property:

- There exists a function $s(i, |x|)$ that *happens to* give the head movement (which is determined by the transition function) on step $i$ for any input $x$ of length $|x|$.

**Are these two notions equivalent, in the sense that they can compute the same functions? If so, how can we simulate each one using the other?**

Also, if these definitions are not equivalent, which one is actually meant by the standard usage of "oblivious Turing machine"?

---

Every type-2 OTM is easily seen to be a type-1 OTM, since we can simply remove the head movement specification from the transition function and define $s$ based on the type-2 OTM's movement. So the question boils down to showing the reverse direction.

Comment: Is s required to be a computable function?

Comment: @Mjiig I guess so? But I think the ideal answer would discuss both cases.

Comment: this is quite a new concept. Its prolly better fit on cstheory or mathoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions are not equivalent, and type 1 is much too strong.

Take a uncomputable function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n) \geq n$. Take the movement function $$s(i, n) = \begin{cases}\rightarrow, &\text{if $i \leq f(n)$} \\ \downarrow, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
And the transition function which writes $b$ if it sees $a$ or blank, and stops if it sees $b$. The resulting type 1 machine transforms $a^n$ to $b^{f(n)}$, thus computing an uncomputable function.

This definition is in fact more similar to Turing machine with advice (used for example to define the class $\mathrm{P/poly}$). The usual definition of the oblivious TM is the second one, as in Arora&Barak.